# Python Mailgun doesn't send emails

Tags: python, api, email, flask, mailgun

I am just trying to send emails through Mailgun with Python and Flask. But I never receive this email. Even on Mailgun dashboard isn't any email. I am testing it with postman and time response is around 1300 ms, so something is obviously happening. I really don't know what is wrong .

Here is my code:

```
    from flask import request, url_for
    from requests import Response, post
    from typing import Dict, Union
    from db import db

    MAILGUN_DOMAIN = "sandboxb52127d48d2f492fa219b3ba92683cc4.mailgun.org"
    MAILGUN_API_KEY = "a683************"
    FROM_TITLE = "My Application"
    FROM_EMAIL = "mailgun@sandboxb52127d48d2f492fa219b3ba92683cc4.mailgun.org"



    def send_confirmation_email(self) -> Response:
        return post(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{MAILGUN_DOMAIN}/messages",
            auth= ("api", MAILGUN_API_KEY),
            data={"from": "{FROM_TITLE} <{FROM_EMAIL}>",
                  "to": self.email,
                  "subject": "Hello",
                  "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
            }
        )
```

Comment: Whats the HTTP status code from `post(...)` ?

Comment: status code is 200

Answer (score 0):

If you use sandbox, you must add Authorized Recipients email and confirm it.